# Creating User Controls without predefined properties C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

I am aiming at creating different `UserControls` for my college project, in which I am attempting to use `ContentControl` to wrap my `UserControl`. I've placed other Controls like `Image`, `WebBrowser`, `MediaElement` and the like, now I have reached a stage where I need to set the properties for my `UserControls`. Thus, I thought of making use of `PropertyGrid` Control, but now the problem I am facing is in the `PropertyGrid` control, as I get all the default properties of the Controls, which in my case I don't want.

For Eg: if I use Image Control then i need properties like Source and Stretch to be displayed only in the `PropertyGrid`. Can anyone help me in achieving this?

I tried to override some default properties like "Name" and assign it as `[Browsable(false)]` to hide it from being displayed. I don't want to do this for all the other properties which are being displayed and which are not under my requirements as well.

I am using `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit` for my `PropertyGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in the documentation on how to do that:

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid

[image]

When you change the selected object see `SelectedObjectType` and set `PropertyDefinitions` in code to match the properties you want to see for that type of object.